# Как сохранить график на Google диске

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

x = [1, 3, 5, 6]
y = [2, 5, 6, 8]
for i in range (0, len(x)):
    plt.scatter(x[i], y[i], color = "red", s = 90)
plt.plot(x, y, color = "black", linewidth = 1)
plt.xlabel('Дата')
plt.ylabel('Настроение')
```

Как полученный график выложить в Гугл диск?

Comment: Вам в любом случае придётся пользоваться памятью. Поймите, код выше и само представление графика понятно только интерпретатору Python. Чтобы загрузить что-то на Google диск или на сервер ВК, Вам это что-то нужно сохранить в память и не важно как и в каком формате. Объясните, почему Вы не рассматриваете такой вариант?

Comment: @nomnoms12 Вк API должен получить ссылку. Для этого нужно либо куда-то выложить картинку либо скачать её. Мы не хотим её скачивать

Comment: Вы не правы. Отправка фото (и других файлов) в vk устроена так: 1) Вы отправляете запрос на загрузку файла. ВК api возвращает Вам в ответ ссылку, на которую Вы должны отправить файл. 2) Вы загружаете файл на сервер ВК. ВК отправляет Вам в ответ id, по которому Вы можете обращаться к фотографии. 3) Вы отправляете сообщение и прикрепляете к нему id фотографии. Вот ссылки на официальную документацию ВК api: [загрузка фотографии в личное сообщение](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=4.%20Загрузка%20фотографии%20в%20личное%20сообщение), [отправка сообщения](https://vk.com/dev/messages.send)

Comment: @nomnoms12 Но файл, который я загружаю на сервер, загружается с компа. Я не хочу так делать

Comment: А как по-вашему можно загрузить файл с компьютера на сервер без использования компьютера? Я не понимаю Вас. График хранится на компьютере, следовательно только с этого компьютера его можно передать. Не использовать при этом память не получится, будь то оперативная или постоянная. Ваш скрипт и так занимает память (оперативную), так почему Вас не устраивает этот вариант? Может Вы просто хотите использовать хостинг или сервер? Если я Вас неправильно понял, объясните, пожалуйста, общую идею того, что Вы хотите.